# Not able to resize background image in HTML, CSS in the way I want to

Tags: html, css

I wanted to resize the image in such a way that the image gets resized according to the resolution of the screen it is being displayed on.
I found a code that does it perfectly :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
html,body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color : black;
}

img {
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="kara.jpg" align="right" />
</body>
</html>
```

At the center of this image I want to play a video, but since it's not a background image it wasn't possible. 
But, using background-image in CSS I am not able to get the same effect that the above gives me.
I tried a combination of many properties like background-size , background-position etc. It just didn't give me the same kind of output. 
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna it take exactly the same width and height of the image, you can write the following

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html,body {
    height: 100%;
   width : 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color : black;
}
.image {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
   background : url(https://via.placeholder.com/150) no-repeat center center;
}
  .image img{
   opacity : 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

else you can do it using position absolute, like the following

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html,body {
    height: 100%;
   width : 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color : black;
}
.image {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
   position : absolute;
    top : 0px;
    left : 0px;
   background : url(https://via.placeholder.com/150) no-repeat top center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="image"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
body{
 padding : 0px;
    margin : 0px;
}
.container{
 width : 100vw;
    height : 100vh;
    position : relative;   
}
.container img{
 width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    display : block;
    margin : 0px auto;
}
.container video{
 width : auto;
 position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
    <video width="400" controls>
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
 </video>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, the snippet I posted basically resizes the image according to the screen's resolution. It can't even be tested unless you have screens of different resolution available I guess. Both your solutions mess up the height of the image but thanks, I appreciate the answer and I should probably edit my question a bit.

Comment: I've added another example, this example is if the image will take full width and height, and the video is centered in the image, i hope that this is the result you need :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest wrapping your image in a container that wont limit it and then center your video in that container:

```
<style>
html,body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color : black;
}

section {
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  position: relative;
  padding:0;
}
// I made up the video tag for the example, use what you need
video {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 800px; // example
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 500px;. // example
  top: calc(50% - 250px); // 500/2
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<section>
<img src="kara.jpg" align="right" />
<video />
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The video does not get centered. I tinkered a bit with your settings as well but the video just won't go on top of the image. 
Also, the image does not get resized properly, have to scroll down to see the lower portion of the image.